# Text Gallery on Android?

Tags: android, gallery

I have a gallery with the `TextView` to achieve the segment controller on the image below. I can achieve it by the ApiDemo's Gallery Example but I am lagging on the look and feel of the gallery.

I want to do the backgrounds, Selected/deselected and selected item won't be cone to the center of the screen.

Any Idea or Articles are most Thankful.

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cce47da969.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cce47da969.png)

I have tried to get using 2 ways. that are:

1. `Gallery View`
2. `horizontal ScrollView`

The ouput getting is in the below image:

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b4c1be5924.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b4c1be5924.png)

I have Problem on Both to get the proper output.

In Gallery View,

- can not Change Background of Selected
  Item.and make it us rounded corner.
- Selected Item comes to the center horizontal of the Screen Automatically.

In horizontal View,

- More Complicated when the `textView`'s number is large.
- Can not find a way similar to On Click Item. if i have use switch case. the previous problem comes again.

Comment: @praveen-chandrasekaran: Sorry for the offtopic but what is your add in the button. It doesn't look like admob's.

Comment: @Macarse: thats Google Adsense for mobile: check this link: http://www.google.com/mobileads/publisher_home.html

Comment: Hi @Praveen, Plz share the code of this gallery. I am also tried this and apply all things which are below but not succeeded plz help....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

place this in drawables text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round" />
</selector>
```

round.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#FFEF95" android:endColor="#FFEF95"   
            android:angle="270"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="14dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="14dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="14dp" android:topRightRadius="14dp"/> 

</shape>
```

round_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#F6A110" android:centerColor="#FFEF95" android:endColor="#F6A110"   
            android:angle="270"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="14dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="14dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="14dp" android:topRightRadius="14dp"/> 

</shape>
```

And here is the textview to inflate

```
 <TextView    
        android:id="@+id/perioxi_select" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Area"
         android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         android:background="@drawable/text_selector"
         android:minHeight="60dp"
         style="@style/FirstText"   
         android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Get the style too. should be placed inside res/valus/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
 <style name="FirstText"> 
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#f0f</item> 
        <item name="android:padding">4sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">#CC3300</item> 
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item> 
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#999</item> 
    </style> 
  </resources>
```

Comment: sorry. It happens mistakenly. i thought just upvote you. your answer is not accurate. But I got some Idea.Thanks. please edit your answer.

Comment: it is accurate you just set android:background="@drawable/text_selector" to the element of your gallery (i suppose it's a TextView).. save round.xml round_selected.xml and text_selector.xml to /res/drawables and you're done.Rounded corners and when you press them change color.

Comment: no you are wrong.  you text_selector.xml shows all elements with the rounded corner background. But I would need to show just the selected item only have the rounded corner. I found the answer from android git kernal what are the states we have to define is in this link : http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/gallery_item_background.xml;h=c7eb7ea8b93c5022fe6710e87a552ca0fa47604f;hb=HEAD check it.

Comment: well you just define another round_* for your needs..not that hard to adapt it to your needs since i posted all the code...

Comment: @weakwire: can you tell me when we select an item in `GalleryView` its  comes to the center of the screen howto restrict it? I want to just be there where i click that item. How?

Comment: Wild guess?override and Implement  GalleryView and create a custom view but it's a long shot.in a recent project of mine i created a "Subject Selector" line.If that's the "control" you want to do ..I created it using a horizontal scrollview and Couple of TextViews.Textviews can be added to the Scrollview runtime so you don't really have a limit and can change it dynamically (A good reference to that is gridview example of the SDK)