# Scrolling ListView Horizontally and Vertically Both In Android

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal ListView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

I am creating a listView by inflating a xml file,,I want my list to be scrolled Horizontal as well as Vertically my content are hiding in left part of screen.

Can someone tell me how to scroll a list horizontally.??

**Updated**

I can use `HorizontalScrollView` But it will scroll horizontally.I want both scrollbar to be enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ListView` use Gallery - it will be scrolled horizontal, and can be filled with datas in the same way as the `ListView`.

EDIT: Look at this post: [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android), there are code samples of what you need.

Comment: but what if go listview as its has several advantage over Gallery

Comment: I've edited my answer, look above.

Comment: its scrolling only horizontally i want both behavior  as needed.If horizontal content is big then it would scroll horizontally as well as vertically\

Comment: I see 2 solutions : implementing your custom Adapter, or using `ScrollView` (only for simple data, because it do not have view caching, and will work slow on larger datas).