# Load data on scroll

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am developing android application. Now I have to create the app of newspaper. So on home page I have to display top stories with the images and the text. Now my problem is, there should be so many top stories so I have used horizontal scroll bar to see other stories. Now my idea is to load the images and the text when the user scrolls left or right. Is it possible to do or I have to load all the data on create of the activity. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What do you use for horizontal scroll? The bar is only an indicator, gallery? Workspaces? Another library?

Comment: What you are asking about is lazy-loading. And try using listView instead of scroll-bars

Comment: either load all data in AsyncTask or you can load data in your adapter's getView method...but the first option is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking about is Lazy-Loading, then you need to use `AsyncTask`, as it's the easiest method to implement it.

```
class Download extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Integer>{
     protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... wat) {
          //Your downloading stuff
     }
     protected Integer onPostExecute(Integer result){
           //Create listview in UI Thread
     }
}
```

To create an horizontal ListView read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)