# How to set the ListView with Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

I am working on android and I want to make `ListView` to scroll Horizontal.
Is there any idea to do it using android property for `ListView`?
Please help me.

Comment: why don't you use either Gallery or ViewPager? afaik, ListView isn't supposed to be used in that way

Comment: can you give me one example of Gallery view

Answer (score 1):

There is an excelent article about this on dev-smart

[Horizontal Scroll in ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of :

[Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

And there is one more example :

http://nan-devblog.blogspot.in/2008/12/android-how-to-use-horizontal-scrolling.html