# Widget used for entering numbers (screenshot attached)

Tags: android, android-widget

I like the UI in Libra (It is an app used for keeping track of your weight).

I would love to use a similar widget for entering numbers. I have been unable to find anything that looks like it. Was it custom made for just this app or does it come from some UI toolkit?

[image: Widget used for entering numbers in Libra]

Comment: I think it's a home made and it didn't seems very difficult to recreate it !

Comment: So how do you think it was made - layout-wise that is?

Comment: It might be something as "simple" as a [horizontal ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android). Yeah, that would work I think. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered so I am answering it myself.

After doing some research, I see that the widget from the image was implemented using [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html). Since Gallery should not be used any more I think that one can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead.