# Customized Android Radio Button [Not their look and feel... ;) ]

Tags: android, radio-button, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I know well that there are ways of customizing elements like `GridView` and `ListView` through the use of `Adapters` (like `BaseAdapter`).
I am also aware of the Holder paradigm to keep the state of complex data structures.

I am wondering if the `RadioGroup` works the same. If not how could I implement something like this:

```
|-------|
| TEXT  |
|-------|
| IMAGE |
|-------|
| RADIO |
|  BUT. |
|-------|
```

That can be added modularly (programmatically) to a `RadioGroup` to obtain more complex structures like this one:

```
|-------|-------|-------|
| TEXT  | TEXT  | TEXT  |
|-------|-------|-------|
| IMAGE | IMAGE | IMAGE |
|-------|-------|-------|
| RADIO | RADIO | RADIO |
|  BUT. |  BUT. |  BUT. |
|-------|-------|-------|
```

Other solutions that I have found involve [Horizontal ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android) or customized  [GridView](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/).

Is there any other Android design pattern that may be followed to achieve a more elegant result?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use something like this to create custom radiogroup buttons which function like tabs : http://blog.mokriya.com/post/15342694933/custom-tabs-in-android
As for your question about adding them dynamically you can set their views visible or not but i dont think that would be the most feasible solution :)

Comment: Thanks @Android2390 probably the only way of doing it is to extend the `RadioButton` class itself and create a custom layout that takes into account all the elements I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the only way I've found for doing this is a lot of coding in JAVA.
Base adapter + ViewHolder paradigm + hardcoded generation of Linear Layouts with the wanted components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if i completely understood your question, but looking at the ilustration, i assume, that you need to extend the [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) class, and add some custom functionality.

Comment: Thanks @bali182 but I think it is not what I meant.
What I meant was something similar to the process in ListView, where you can customize your element in a different XML layout and then expand it (inflate) into your ListView.