# How to use horizontal scroll in listview?

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I am working on an android app. There is `Layout` created in which different layout included.

There is a `listview` also in it. I used `custom adapter` for `listview` . I want to show horizontal scroll in `listview` .But when i apply horizontal scroll in it, it shows for each item. but  not in last.

Please suggest how can i apply this.

code is given below:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_header" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenHeader"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_list_header" >
</include>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenListHeader"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenFilterClient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_filter_client" >
</include>

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainScreenFilterClient"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    layout="@layout/footer" >
</include>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this library you cal try this one:

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Answer (score 1):

There is an excelent article about this on dev-smart

[Horizontal Scroll in ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

check this

Comment: earlier i was using above but i had some issue with this. Don't know may be it will be working for you.
Here is some liks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397715/touch-event-not-working-with-horizontal-list-view-devsmart-lib

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `HorizontalListView` in the `xml` file:

```
    HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: i am adding horizontal scroll but it is appearing for each item of list .scroll at each row of list view.

Answer (score 0):

This will Help you..

```
<com.devsmart.android.ui.horizontiallistview 
android:id="@+id/listview" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ddd">
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: android:orientation="horizon..." where this should use.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the Adapter by declaring several types of views. Then for every element you return the 1st type of view and for last one - second which would be a HorizontalScrollView.:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isLastPositionInList ? 1 : 0;
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch(itemViewType) {
        case 0:
           // prepare here your usual view
        case 1:
           // prepare here the horizontal view
```