# touch event not working with horizontal list view (devsmart lib)

Tags: android-listview, touch, horizontallist

I have implemented horizontal list view inside vertical list view using librarty: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android.

It is working fine.
I have to implement touch listener on list view to manage visibilty of header view (similar to google chrome's android app'd URL bar). Touch listener works normally for list view (if horizontal list view is not inflated in it). But when user touches the list cell having horizontal list view, then touch event is not handled.

I have also noticed that in horizontal list view, on touch is overridden to manage its scroll.

I also tested this on a list view (having no horizontal list view), and it worked fine.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution. You need to override the `onTouchEvent()` as given in following answer-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882050/609782