# Make a mask on a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, mask

I need to make a mask on an HorizontalLinear Layout.
the mask must blear (sfumate) the layout at right and left.
In the layout i'have 5 picture, tha can scroll horizontally

Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You an horizontal scroll view from devian [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3240331/693752).

For the dimming, this may be tricky, you could maybe just add some imageview to each side of the list, but you will have to re-implement it I think, not sure.

Comment: i can't add two image with trasparency, because the backgroudn is not omogeneous, and the user see difference between layout and background

Comment: I saw the library, but it is too large and complex, I need a simple code ^^

Comment: thanks.. i do it with a picture (i can't upload because i'have to low reputation)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the ImageView in a FrameLayout, when the mask should be shown, on FrameLayout.setForegroundDrawable(arg) . The 'arg' is drawable with a transparent color value.
Hope it helps.