# Android: Horizontal Scrolling Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am looking for a horizontal scrolling list view for a application. So that i can make a table which scrolls horizontally something like [image].

But found that Android does not has a horizontal scrolling ListView widget any suggestions?

Comment: Use HorizontalScrollView and inflate the items that you want to list programatically.

Comment: use this HorizontalLisView http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Comment: I used @RajaReddyPolamReddy 's link in my project though Sandy09 's answer was also simple to implement. Haven't tried rest of the solutions.

Comment: try working code http://indrapatel.blogspot.in/2013/10/horizontal-listview-in-android.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal ListView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this project, maybe this is what you need.
https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

Comment: Bingo! Only if i would have found it earlier. This is really an awesome piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use horizontal scroll view and add the elements in scroll view programatically at runtime

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custom listview if you want to make it horizontal this is a very nice and direct example :
http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html