# how to create different page on the same activity

Tags: android

I have a cursor that contains several items and I need to place each item on a page and I want to be able to scroll between pages by scrolling left and right...
I think it's a horizontal list view but couldn't figure out how to do it...
thnaks.

**edit:**
how can I add the content of the cursor to the viewpager?

Comment: What you need is a ViewPager or HorizontalListView? Please explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: hi thanks for your reply I need to add the content of my cursor in a way that each item comes on a page... it's the viewpager as you mentioned I think but is there a way to use it with a cursor and please how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is what you need. Take a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) tutorial

Comment: is there a way to use the viewpager with a cursor I am searching but can't find what I need I need to get the data of the viewpager from a cursor...

Comment: You can use CursorLoader for this purposes. This question seems to be similar with your one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760647/viewpager-pageradapter-with-cursor-cursorloader-onloadfinished-doesnt-get-call

Answer (score 1):

for such purpose i use [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)
you can find a simple example [here](http://moorandroid.blogspot.com/p/gallery-view.html)
**EDIT**
since you have your adapter ready you can apply it to[Horizontal ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829092/android-horizontal-scrolling-listview)

Comment: no that's not what I want I saw how the horizontal list view shows on the app but I don't want that I think what I need is the viewpager but thanks.