# how to Set Orientation to listview - android

Tags: android

I've set android:screenOrientation="portrait" to my activity.

My activity have 2 listview.

i need to set one list view in portrait

and another one list view in landscape.

[image]

how to set orientation two list view.

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with built in `ListView` control.

I can suggest alternative, which is called `TwoWayGridView`: https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

There are probably many projects like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You should use this plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589629/2075875 (I mean there is rotate function, but it doesn't work properly - it doesn't fit into screen and is supported only in new devices.)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for horizontal-listview with a custom TextView that's rotated in -90 degree

http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html