# How can I achieve Horizontal Listview Smooth Scrolling using left and right arrows?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

I am referring this tutorial.
http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

How can I achieve smooth left and right scrolling using on touch listener on left and right arrows? Any help will be highly thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicated question please check this:
[Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Also you can check navigation swipe views in the following link
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I have achieved this using offset calculating. My question was how can i scroll horizontol scrollview on next and previous arrows.