# How to create a horizontal list view? Android

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling

I am having a hard time creating a horizontal listview, I want all the items to be scrollable horizontally. I tried this but the list still appears in its regular format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST TO SEE IF HORIZ"/>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewGlobal"
            android:ori>

            </ListView>


    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create horizontal list you can use:

1)`RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` or `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`

2) [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are putting a `ListView` inside an `HorizontalScrollView` and the vertical scroll that you are experiencing is caused by the `ListView`.

Change your `ListView` for a `LinearLayout` inside you `HorizontalScrollView` to make it work.

Also, take a look at [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)