# Library for Showing 3 Images in a Horizondal Grid

Tags: android, gallery

I want to show 3 images from URL(Now fetching Using Picasso) in a Horizondal Grid.
Is there a library to so that or do i need to code starting from the bottom?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show just 3 images, why don't you just use a `LinearLayout` containing 3 `ImageView`s, each with a `layout_weight` of  `1`?

Have a look at this answer: [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android). It will link you to open-source libraries. You could either look at them and come up with your own implementation or use them as-is.

Another option is to use a `ViewPager`.

Yet another option is to use a `RecyclerView` with [`LinearLayoutManager`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html#recycleview).

Comment: Thanks but i need this 3 image gallery within a fragment.Will this http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 approach work?

Comment: @techno I suggest you look at `RecyclerView` first. It ships with Android API Level 21 and is available via compatibility library for pre-Lollipop devices.