# Scroll 5 rows horizontall - List View, Grid View

Tags: android, listview, gridview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

Is there any easy solution, library or suggestion, to have 1 column with 5 rows, and to scroll left to right? So basically i need to scroll 5 rows horizontally.

[image]

Comment: share any screens and your code till you have tried.

Comment: I'm not clear your question, but if you want to display 5 column in 1 row, and scroll it left to right, the easy way to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: I added a picture to be more precise

Comment: Use RecycleView for horizontal scrolling or HorizontalScrollView

Comment: have a look at this link, it could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android

Comment: Accomplished with RecyclerView