# Customizing UI elements in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am naive to Android development. I believe Android Studio is super cool and made life easier but there is something I am stuck with for hours.

I want to make a UI element exactly like shown below. It will contain a person name and check box. 
[image]

I want to select people and I want in this way.

Please can anyone tell me how to construct this UI element and how to use these elements horizontaly in list view ?

Comment: **exactly** like the image, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the same as you expected.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="David cooper"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these attributes in your checkbox object to have the text on left and the checkbox on right:

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

Comment: @AdilMalik if you need to play with padding (and who knows what else), you are better of creating a custom layout with a textbox and a checkbox.

Comment: No Custom Layout is more complex. I solved it putting 2 spaces before name (which looks like padding from left side :P)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<CheckBox
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="person_name"
  android:background="@drawable/stroke.xml"
  android:checked="false" />
```

`stroke.xml` in your drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#606060"/>
<stroke android:color="#303030" android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Make this as a layout of your listView

To make a Listview with multiple Checkboxes

1. Make a ArrayList of Data you want in your listView
2. Make a CustomAdapter using BaseAdapter
3. Pass the ArrayList to the Adapter
4. Now set your Checkboxes content to the values in your Arraylist 
   like `arraylist.get(postion).names`

You can checkout this [sample code](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) on implementation of Listview with Checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, I know how to make things work with list adapter. But I don't know how to make listView horizontal

Comment: Another thing is that i am confused about that how can i add padding from stroke background ?

Comment: If you want a Grid like layout, i would suggest moving on to the `RecyclerView` as it handles the orientation with `LayoutManagers`. And adding padding to your checkbox element with background as a stroke would work just fine according to me

Comment: @AdilMalik check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android it may help

Answer (score 0):

You likely want a `LinearLayout`, orientation horizontal, containing a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Will probably a lot of help