# Horizontal scrolling of list item on at a time like facebook friend suggestion list in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to implement a list that has some card which scroll horizontally (scroll one item at a time like  facebook friend suggestion list). [image]

Comment: use 'RecyclerView' with horisontal 'LinearLayoutManager'

Comment: just use scrollbars horizontal

Comment: Refer to this link:http://stackoverflow.com/a/29648713/7316510

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal ListView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView & set layout manager to that like this

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
     @Override
     public boolean canScrollVertically() {
           return false;
     }
});
```

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

for set horizontal RecyclerView use :

```
 LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and for showing horizontal scrollBar in RecyclerView , in xml layout :

```
 android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

and with this line you can set custom scrollBar:

```
 android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/recycler_scroll"
```