# Can't scroll ListView in landscape mode

Tags: android, listview

I can scroll my `ListView` without any problem in portrait mode, but in landscape mode it doesn't scroll at all.

My `ListView` is inside a `LinearLayout` (vertical). I have 10 items in the `ListView`. I can scroll all of them in portrait mode. In landscape mode I see only 6 items, and the scroll doesn't work. Any solution for this?
my xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="480dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollIndicators="end"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: can post your xml?

Comment: @akshay_shahane thanks for interest
i posted the xml

Comment: I would suggest using a recycler view,its better for performance and efficiency and having a horizontal scroll is a breeze using that.You can follow this thread.https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648713/5132444

Comment: it seems you are using constraint layout why are you linear layout inside constraintlayout does it serve any purpose?

Comment: @akshay_shahane I use constraintLayout because it's by default implemented in android studio and it's the parent of other layouts

Comment: @JudeFernandes thank you i will