# Why is listview items length set by the first item

Tags: android, listview

I created horizontal scrollable listview. And I can populated from db without any problem. The problem is; the entire length of the items are setted to the length of the first item.

[Like this](https://pasteboard.co/GJZTLsi.png)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html. You could use a ReyclerView for this purpose

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution to this problem is to use **Recyclerview** instead of List View.
Adding HorizontalScrollview to LinearLayout will not work.
I have already tried many solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android) 
after a lot of search I come to this point my solution was Recyclerview.
And from [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView) i learned,How to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make listView height match the parent

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
   <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```