# Android HorizontalScrollView appearing as Vertical

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

Hi I want to create a horizontal scrollview but it comes out as vertical. Can you help?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/household_member_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is what appears:

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are using a HorizontalScrollView? Is it to create a horizontal ListView?

Comment: Use recyclerview instead of listview to easily create horizontal behaviour

Comment: Hi Udesh. Yes, I am trying to create a horizontal ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using *ListView* inside of *ScrollView*, this will not work.

If you want to have horizontal *ListView* you need to use **RecyclerView**

More here:
[Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recyclerview.
Set horizontal linear layout as layoutmanager for recyclerview to achieve horizontal scrolling