# How to make a ListView scrollable horizontally(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to know how can I make a 'ListView' to be scrollable horizontally in Xamarin.Android .

Comment: Use `RecyclerView` instead, you can make vertical, horizontal and even grid views using it. it also have some more advantages over `ListView`. see [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The best practise is to use `RecyclerView` as google recommended, and with `LinearLayoutManager`, items can be shown vertically or horizontally.

For details of implementing a recyclerView, you can refer to `RecyclerView`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/

If you insist on using `listview` to achieved the scrollable horizontally, you can refer to Paul [Soucy's HorizontalListView.java](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java) and [cheesebaron's C# implementation](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.HorizontalListView) of that

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I put in the layout file to make it work.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" >
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/BarcodeChorusLocalizationListView" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I help you to up vote, I guess reason of downvote, because you didnot upload your code and what have you achieved now?

Comment: But this issue, you should use `RecyclerView` to achieve that

Comment: I am in a hurry to make it and I don't have time to remember how to work with RecyclerViews , so I wanted to know how to make it with ListView. I resolved the problem putting my ListView in a HorizontalScrollView. I put the code in my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please mark your reply as answer. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.