# How to set delay in "onItemSelected()" function in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using a menu in my application same as this post... I am using a gallery view for display my menu items.

[Text Gallery on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237566/text-gallery-on-android)

Problem is that, i implement `onItemSelected` listener for gallery, so that when new item is selected data related to that topic loaded. **But i also want to allow user to scroll the gallery fully**. But each time when user move to next item `onItemSelected()` function called and it start loading data.

All i want to do is to put some delay in `onItemSelected()` function, so that if in between that delay user scroll next item than there is no need to load data of previous but for the current. Time may be 1 second. If user dose not go for next item in 1 second, that data of that item must be loaded.

Can anyone help? I thought to start a thread, but each time for `onItemSelected()` there will be new thread...

**I tried this too**

```
public class TimerThreadForCategoriesMenu extends Thread{

int old = -1;
int cur = -1;
CategoriesActivity catAct = null;

public TimerThreadForCategoriesMenu(CategoriesActivity act , int cu) {
    this.cur = cu;
    old = cu;
    this.catAct = act;

}
@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();

    do{
        old = this.cur;
        for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }while(cur != old);
    catAct.performTask();
    Looper.loop();  
}

public void setCur (int curr){
    this.cur = curr;
}

}
```

And in `OnItemSelected()`

```
      if(timer == null){  

        timer = new TimerThreadForCategoriesMenu(this, arg2);
        timer.start();
    }
    timer.setCur(curInd);
```

Found Exception:

> 11-24 16:48:50.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:570)
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:596)
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2396)
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:4945)
>   11-24 16:48:50.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8049):     at

Comment: ok, nearly there.  what you need to do is create a Handler in the Activity so you can post a Runnable to the UI thread to update the UI component.

Comment: also it would be better not to have the thread loop with the do..while (that is what the looper.prepare stuff does).  create another handler in your thread and post a Runnable to it.

Comment: I can't understand. Can you put some code?

Comment: ok.  i'll edit my original answer.

Comment: Hopefully the code makes more sense. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `Handler` and `postDelayed()` a `Runnable`

Edit:

It depends on what processing you wish to do.
Have a look at `Looper` in the reference.  The UI has its own `Looper` so you don't need to create one.  Just create a `Handler`, however any `Runnable` posted to the UI Thread Handler will be run on the UI thread.  If you are doing stuff that takes a while to complete, create you're own `Thread` with a `Handler` and post `Runnables` to that.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Edit:

So create members in your Activity.

```
Handler handler;
MyLooper mylooper;
```

Your thread looper.

```
class MyLooper extends Thread {
  public Handler handler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      handler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {}
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
}
```

In your `Activity.onCreate`.

```
handler = new Handler();
mylooper = new MyLooper();
```

Now create `Runnable`s.

```
Runnable processinfo = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //  your processing here
    }
}

Runnable updateui = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //  update ui component here
    }
}
```

Now to get these `Runnables` to execute.

```
mylooper.handler.postDelayed(processinfo, 1000);

handler.post(updateui);
```

You will need some logic to handle cancelling the `Runnable` based on the needs of your delay.

Comment: @Arsian: hope that helps.  if not let me know.

Comment: can you show me what you have done please?  also what is the exception message?

Comment: yeah i commented under your edit. let me know if it don't make sense.

Comment: Can plz tell? How can i add ScrollView to gallery?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Did you get the thread handlers working?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same requirement, since onItemSelected will be called so often if the user spinning through the Gallery I wanted to avoid these events. I implemented a simple delay mechanism with Handler as follows:

Define a handler instance in the Activity class and override **handleMessage** which should have the onItemSelected logic. Here, I've the msg.obj contains the text of the selectedItem from the Gallery

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    // Add your OnItemSelected code here
        Log.d("Gallery", msg.obj + "");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg.obj + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
};
```

This is just an arbitrary constant to refer to the message that I send from OnItemSelected

```
public static final int MSG_ITEM_SELECTION = 1;
```

In onItemSelected I first remove any previous message to avoid firing the event while user spinning the Gallery, and then add a new message object with the selected item text and post it with a 500 ms delay.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            handler.removeMessages(MSG_ITEM_SELECTION);
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MSG_ITEM_SELECTION);
            msg.obj = ((TextView) view).getText();
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 500);
        }
```

This code works fine for me, and I only receive the onItemSelected when a Gallery item is really selected after spinning stops.