# How to highlight item currently selected in a gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I've come with a problem. I need to highlight the selected item within a Gallery. I've tried changing the appearance of the selected view through this method:

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The second parameter of that view is the current selected view, and I'm trying in this case, increase the size of the text. However this doesn't work, not even if I call invalidate in the selected item or in the entire Gallery.

This is the code I use to change the textview text size

```
TextView textview = (TextView)view;             
textview.setTextSize(50, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
textview.invalidate();
```

Do you know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) - looks apt for your situation.

UPDATE: You have reversed the parameters in setTextSize. It should be:

```
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 50);
```

Comment: Hi Rajath, yes it seems that I need to define a StateListDrawable. Similar to this other question that already has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237566/text-gallery-on-android. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to set the text bigger using selectors though. Because selector seem to work with drawables, and in my case I just want to increase the size of the text

Comment: If your purpose is to only highlight the selected item, why would elect text size increase over using StateListDrawable?

Comment: because the Gallery is of TextView items, and the only thing I want to do is increase the TextView size on selection. At the end the results should be similar to the macosx dock effect but with text

Comment: Actually I would need to do other tricks with other galleries as well, as for example display the image title on selection

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant code on how you increase the text size. Also, are you validating whether the view you use IS the TextView?

Comment: Thanks, actually that works, the text is getting trimmed in the top and the bottom, but I guess I just need to figure out that; maybe is related to the layout

Answer (score 8):

Your implementation works, but it does not return the text size to normal once the item becomes unselected - the text stays larger size.

This should fix it:

```
    private View lastview;

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    if (lastview != null) lastview.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    lastview = arg1;
    arg1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);

}
```

You can set text size instead of color, or do whatever you want to the style of it.